# Passing C# Inline Variable to Javascript Function in ASP.Net Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a very simple button click event in an ASP.Net application that calls a very simple javascript function to export the string of text passed to the function to a csv file.  The button click event and the function it calls works perfectly if I pass it a raw string like this:

```
<button onclick="download_csv('TEST')">Download CSV</button>
```

However, if I pass a C# inline string variable like this, it breaks.

```
<button onclick="download_csv(<%=csvExport%>)">Download CSV</button>
```

This is the javascript function.

```
function download_csv(x) {

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(x);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'pricing.csv';
hiddenElement.click();
}
```

The csvExport variable is declared in the .cs file behind the .aspx file and it is filled with a simple string of text; I've actually got it set to "Test" right now for testing.  I've tried wrapping csvExport with single quotes, but that doesn't seem to work either.  I must be missing something really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is filled with a simple string of text

Strings require quotes, whether in C# or in JavaScript.  Your hard-coded example has them:

```
<button onclick="download_csv('TEST')">Download CSV</button>
```

But your dynamic example doesn't:

```
<button onclick="download_csv(<%=csvExport%>)">Download CSV</button>
```

Look at your generated page source to see the value:

```
<button onclick="download_csv(Test)">Download CSV</button>
```

And the resulting syntax error in your browser's development console.  (Both of which should *always* be the first place you look.  If you're not familiar with your browser's development tools, press F12 in Chrome.  There is *a lot* of development and debugging capability there.)

> I've tried wrapping csvExport with single quotes

You don't show that attempt, but from that description it sounds like you tried to do that in the server-side code.  Which would just output the string value `"csvExport"` but without quotes in your JavaScript code it would fail the same way for the same reason.

Just put your quotes back:

```
<button onclick="download_csv('<%=csvExport%>')">Download CSV</button>
```

Comment: Wrapping the inline C# with single quotes solved the problem.  I feel dumb, but THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're missing quotes around your text. You can debug this by using Chrome's dev tools to inspect the source of the page and see what .net is actually outputting.

Also, if your download link can ever contain user data, it's **very important** that you escape it to prevent XSS using [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?view=netframework-4.8)

```
<button onclick="download_csv('<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(csvExport) %>')">Download CSV</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.   Although user data will not be included, I wrapped csvExport with the string encoding just to be safe.